# Getting Error "this._initialize is not a function" while using mangojs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Here is my code.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var mangojs = require("mangojs");
var db = mangojs('mongodb://***:***@XXXXXX.mlab.com:43900/tasks', ['tasks']);

router.get("/tasks", function(req, res, next){

    db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks){

        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        else{
            res.json(tasks);
        }

    });

});
```

by running this getting below error on node.js terminal

this._initialize is not a function >> Attaching an image of error message in terminal.

[image]

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 2):

You want to be using [`mongojs`](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs), not `mangojs`.

Answer (score 2):

The mangojs library is very old so you might consider trying to use something newer and more fleshed out. There also doesn't seem to be much documentation on how to use it.

However, I did find [some notes in the package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mangojs).

```
// Initialize Mango.js 
var mango = new Mango(opts);
```

In the actual code, it boils down to:

```
module.exports = function (options) {
  this._initialize(options);
};
```

You need the `new` keyword for `this` to work properly.

Are you sure you don't want a MongoDB library instead?

Comment: I'm not pretty sure what to use, I just jump in the MEAN development.